# Updating/using a variable from another ViewModel

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm

In order to practice WPF+MVVM, I've decided to write a school program.
So far I have the class and student classes.
There is also the basic view model, ViewModelBase.cs, which derives from INPC, and instances class - "StudentClass".

All other viewmodels derive from viewmodelbase.

The thing is I have a page/window for each "feature", (for example; viewing all of the students, adding a student, deleting a student etc...) and I want to be able to access that class from anywhere in the application since all of the info is stored there basically.

In order to stay organized, each "feature" has its own viewmodel (StudentListViewModel.cs, AddStudentViewModel.cs...).

I tried to access the class from the viewmodels, which just caused a case where the class updates in one window and not in the other.

When I set the viewmodels of the "student list" window, and "add a student" window, the list are sync-ed, obviously. So I guess the thing is the class instance gets duplicated or something like that.

I've uploaded the project for reference: http://www.mediafire.com/?n70c7caqex6be1g

Hopefully someone can help me.

I tried looking on google for answers, but all of the answers mentions "Messengers" and "events" which are related to frameworks. And since I didn't use a framework for this project, those solutions doesn't apply for me.

Another solution was to pass an instance of the viewmodel to another, but none of my viewmodels call or instantiate another viewmodel.

Update:

XAML in StudentList.xaml: (This is a usercontrol because I'm using a template called ModernUI)

```
<UserControl x:Class="ClassStudent.StudentList"
         xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
         xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
         xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
         xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
         mc:Ignorable="d" 
         d:DesignHeight="300" d:DesignWidth="300" DataContext="{StaticResource StudentListViewModel}">
<Grid Style="{StaticResource ContentRoot}">
    <ListView ItemsSource="{Binding StudentClass.StudentList}" >
        <ListView.View>
            <GridView>
                <GridViewColumn Header="Name" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Name}" Width="60"/>
                <GridViewColumn  Header="Age" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding LastName}" Width="60"/>
            </GridView>
        </ListView.View>
    </ListView>
</Grid>
```

XAML in AddStudent.xaml:

```
<UserControl x:Class="ClassStudent.AddStudent"
         xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
         xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
         xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
         xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
         mc:Ignorable="d" 
         d:DesignHeight="300" d:DesignWidth="300">
<Grid Style="{StaticResource ContentRoot}"  DataContext="{StaticResource AddStudentViewModel}">
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
        <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
        <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
        <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
    <Label Content="Name"/>
    <TextBox Text="{Binding Student.Name, Mode=TwoWay}" Grid.Column="1"/>
    <Label Content="Last Name" Grid.Row="1"/>
    <TextBox Text="{Binding Student.LastName, Mode=TwoWay}" Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="1"/>

    <Button Command="{Binding AddStudent}" Content="Add Student!" Grid.Row="2" />
</Grid>
```

AddStudentViewModel.cs:

```
public class AddStudentViewModel : ViewModelBase
{
    private Student _student;
    private ICommand _addStudent;
    private ViewModelBase newIns;

    public ICommand AddStudent
    {
        get
        {
            if (_addStudent == null)
            {
                _addStudent = new RelayCommand(param => this.Add(), null);
            }

            return _addStudent;
        }
    }

    public Student Student
    {
        get
        {
            return _student;
        }
        set
        {
            _student = value;
            NotifyPropertyChanged("Student");
        }
    }

    private void Add()
    {
        StudentClass.StudentList.Add(Student);
        Student = new Student();
    }

    public AddStudentViewModel()
    {
        Student = new Student();
    }
}
```

ViewModelBase.cs:

```
public class ViewModelBase : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    private Class _studclass;

    public Class StudentClass
    {
        get { return _studclass; }
        set
        {
            _studclass = value;
            NotifyPropertyChanged("StudentClass");
        }
    }

    public ViewModelBase()
    {
        StudentClass = new Class();
        Student asaf = new Student();
        asaf.Name = "Asaf";
        asaf.LastName = "biton";
        StudentClass.StudentList.Add(asaf);
    }

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
    protected void NotifyPropertyChanged(string PropertyName)
    {
        if (PropertyChanged != null)
        {
            PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(PropertyName));
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: post some relevant XAML and code. We're not going to download your project just to answer this question.

Comment: Done. Thought it'd be too long so I just uploaded the whole project. But if you say so it's better that way, then there you go. Sorry for not doing it beforehand.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> When I set the viewmodels of the "student list" window, and "add a
>   student" window, the list are sync-ed, obviously. So I guess the thing
>   is the class instance gets duplicated or something like that.

I guest you want to inform or communicate between two view models. So I know two ways to implement a similar mechanism but don't use any framework at here.

1. Build a controller which will keep list of instance view models and then define rule when view model A raise event then call event to B. It will take your efforts a lot.
2. You can look at "observer pattern" to build a publish/ subscribe event. When A raise a publish event the view model B which already register subscribe event to execute the function. I suggest you should apply an EventAggregator pattern will get more generic and can use ubiquitous.

   Follow Martin Fowler:

   > An Event Aggregator acts as a single source of events for many
   >   objects. It registers for all the events of the many objects allowing
   >   clients to register with just the aggregator.

   So you can take look at [EventAggregator](http://martinfowler.com/eaaDev/EventAggregator.html) from Martin Fowler to implement an  EventAggregator by your self or you can use [Prism](http://compositewpf.codeplex.com/) framework with [EventAggregator](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd458915.aspx) pattern already built-in. You can look at The [Caliburn micro framework](http://caliburnmicro.codeplex.com/) as well. It is simple, lightweight which have EventAggreagator pattern and a tons best practices in WPF is one of a best of WPF framework will help you save a lot of efforts when deal with MVVM in WPF.

Comment: Think it is the Observer pattern

Comment: EventAggregator is a oneway street. Once you start using it, you will never return to anything else ;) I love the one that ships with caliburn.micro!

Comment: You right. I love Caliburn micro and Caliburn as well. They are really good frameworks. BTW, Thanks for your comments.

Comment: Thanks. I have heard of Caliburn but I want to be able to at least do it by myself before using frameworks. I couldn't understand much from the link you posted, but I will try to look for it on google.

Comment: Good luck to you. Hopefully, you can understand EventAggragator pattern. It is well-known in WPF. E.g : model A publish a event you want B model and C model will receive notify so you need an object manage the notify event has published from A and it will despatch this notify message to objects which already registered to receive.

Comment: @xTCx It is very good to first try to understand the concept before getting help with it. If you want to know more on caliburn.micro, have a look at http://www.mindscapehq.com/blog/index.php/2012/01/12/caliburn-micro-part-1-getting-started/

Comment: @ToanVo Thank you. I managed to solve it with Caliburn!
The only concern I have is that, using this method I actually need to create X lists, and when the event is fired update all of them. Isn't there a way to use just 1 list for the whole program?

Comment: One list for whole of program? My solution assume base on your context is we can build an common model which contains your list when it receive an notify to update it will update the list and then publish another event to send list to list of registered objects to receive.

Answer (score 1):

You probably have to establish some kind of event mechanism.
Do not bother, this is standard .NET technique.

First of all:
Have a model layer. This is the base your ViewModels adapt to the view.
Perhaps it is just a thin layer between some database and your viewmodels.

Having this, provide an event in your model, telling that your Model has
changed somehow.

```
public event EventHandler<ValueChangedEventArgs> ValuesChanged;

public class ValueChangedEventArgs : System.EventArgs
{
    public readonly string str;

    public ValueChangedEventArgs(string str)
    {
        this.str = str;
    }
}
```

Somewhere in your model, when a value changes, fire that event:

```
protected virtual void OnPriceChanged(ValueChangedEventArgs e)
{
    if (ValuesChanged != null)
        ValuesChanged(this, e);
}
```

Perhaps in a setter of a value in your model.

```
public string StringValue
{
    get
    {
        return stringValue;
    }
    set
    {
        OnPriceChanged(new ValueChangedEventArgs(value));
        stringValue = value;
    }
}
```

Then just subscribe in your ViewModel to that event:

```
public void ValuesChangedHandler(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    // do something with the new value
}

public StudentListViewModel()
{
       yourModel.ValuesChanged += ValuesChangedHandler;
}
```

Comment: Sounds like it could work. However my situation is a little different. In my "Class" model, I only have an ObserableCollection of students, and a constructor. All I do is ADD to the collection, and not set it. So how do I do that?

Comment: The Model-View-ViewModel pattern needs a model. The data you display come from that model, get adapted in the viewmodel and are displayed in the view. Connect Model and ViewModel via Events. Then connect ViewModel and View via Binding. The ObservableCollection is definitly a ViewModel part. In your Model, you have a database connection, a List or something like that.

Comment: I have 2 models though. The class, and the student. The class is a list of students, the student is basically the name,last name, etc...