# Binding a View to a ViewModel, without an "empty" constructor

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, caliburn.micro

In continuation to my previous question "[Updating/using a variable from another ViewModel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16498968/updating-using-a-variable-from-another-viewmodel?noredirect=1#16499154)", I decided to start using Caliburn Micro as a framework.

I set up the Event Aggerator according to this guide http://www.mindscapehq.com/blog/index.php/2012/02/01/caliburn-micro-part-4-the-event-aggregator/ .

The thing is that according to this guide, there should not be an "empty" constructor that takes 0 arguments.

Well, fine.

Now the problem is that I have no idea how to bind a ViewModel to a View now.
Before switching to this framework I used App.xaml and Static resources as datacontext's but I can do it no more since there is not an empty constructor.

How do I solve this problem? I've been trying to solve it for like an hour now and I have achieved absolutely nothing.

Some code:

```
[Export(typeof(ViewModelBase))]
public class ViewModelBase : INotifyPropertyChanged, IHandle<updateEvent>
{
    private Class _studclass;
    public AddStudentViewModel NewModel { get; private set; }

    public Class StudentClass
    {
        get { return _studclass; }
        set
        {
            _studclass = value;
            NotifyPropertyChanged("StudentClass");
        }
    }

    [ImportingConstructor]
    public ViewModelBase(AddStudentViewModel newModel, IEventAggregator events)
    {
        StudentClass = new Class();
        NewModel = newModel;
        Student asaf = new Student();
        asaf.Name = "Asaf";
        StudentClass.StudentList.Add(asaf);
        events.Subscribe(this);
    }

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
    protected void NotifyPropertyChanged(string PropertyName)
    {
        if (PropertyChanged != null)
        {
            PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(PropertyName));
        }
    }

    public void Handle(updateEvent msg)
    {
        StudentClass.StudentList.Add(msg.Student);
    }
}
```

That's the "main" viewmodel. However, I can't bind it to a view, so the data doesn't show... I even tried to set up a fake data... which didn't work so well as you may have guessed.

Answer (score 1):

Caliburn.Micro uses conventions. So if you have a `ShellViewModel` in a *ViewModels* folder, it will look for a `ShellView` in a *Views* folder.

I would recommend having a look at the samples and the [documentation](http://caliburnmicro.codeplex.com/documentation). A good starting point is to install the *Caliburn.Micro.Start* NuGet package (which pulls in Caliburn.Micro) and then edit the *App.xaml* file as described in the documentation.

Essentially, the bootstrapper is an application resource which causes it to be instantiated, which then resolves your shell view model via your configured IoC container, locates the corresponding shell view, does the binding and displays it using the Caliburn.Micro window manager.

You also don't need to implement `INotifyPropertyChanged` on a view model base class. Caliburn.Micro includes a `PropertyChangedBase` type, and a `Screen` type, and `Conductor` types.

Comment: Also worth noting that INPC events are marshalled to the UI thread in `PropertyChangedBase`- which is a tiny but really useful feature